# Custom Tumblr theme wont save because of non-https urls?

Tags: html, http, url, https, tumblr

So yesterday i was happily editing the theme of my tumblr blog and everything was working fine. Go into same blog to day and it brings up thsi when i click save:
"Un oh! We could't save your theme. Looks like your custom theme references assets from non-HTTPS Urls. Please try again using only HTTPS Urls."
Super confusing because not urls have been add since yesterday and everything was fine then. Same thing is happening with my other blogs with custom themes. I even went through and deleted all the urls on the html page just to see if it would do anything and the same alert came up. What is going on ??

Please help

Cheers

Comment: Even if you delete all your custom theme code and press save it still says it references not HTTPS addresses.

Comment: I got that too, but then after I tried poking around enough eventually it seemed to have saved with the new HTML I wanted. This might have had something to do with also modifying advanced settings like Google AMP (f that noise), but I genuinely dunno.

Answer (score 6):

Just had the same problem. Tumblr updated their [Encryption policies](https://tumblr.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/226273528-Encryption).

> If you're a theme developer and you'd like to ensure your themes
> support HTTPS, make sure that any externally hosted resources, such as
> Cascading Style Sheets (CSS) or Javascript files, and even images, are
> served using HTTPS.

---

As we now know that Tumblr requires that we use HTTPS instead of HTTP, here's how can we solve the error:

1. Make sure that you are in the customize section and access "Edit HTML":

[image: Tumblr - Customize Section]

[image: Tumblr - Edit HTML]

2. In the "Edit HTML", press Ctrl+F (or press the Settings button and then "Find and replace"):

[image: Tumblr - Settings - Find and Replace]

3. Search for "http" and Replace with "https" - apply that to all.

[image: Tumblr - Finding and Replacing]

4. As the previous step can cause some links to be "httpss", this needs to be fixed. By accessing the Find and Replace and Search for "httpss" and Replace with "https".

**The steps bellow should solve your problem.** If they don't, see "Extra considerations" below, more specifically, point 1.

---

**Extra considerations**

1. I've done all the above, but it didn't solve my problem. What should I do?

When one has `android-app://`, for example:

```
<link rel="alternate" href="android-app://com.tumblr/tumblr/x-callback-url/blog?blogName=goncalomperes" />
```

One will need to add [**https**], as following:

```
<link rel="alternate" href="android-app:https://com.tumblr/tumblr/x-callback-url/blog?blogName=goncalomperes" />
```

As @mchid suggested [in the comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54088449/custom-tumblr-theme-wont-save-because-of-non-https-urls/66647850#comment117816266_59662048), apart from  `android-app://`, we will also need to do the above for: `"//`, `ios-app://`, and `http-equiv`.

2. Accordingly to [Tumblr support](https://support.tumblr.com/post/138103206102/ssl-security-which-has-been-available-on-the):

> Yet another update: SSL is now being turned on by default for ALL
> Tumblrs that use our Official theme on the web. Even though we don’t
> recommend it, you can still turn it off in your blog settings.

So changing the Encryption section to allow SSL should not be the problem.

Comment: In addition to changing `http://` to `https://` and `android-app://` to `android-app:https://` I also had to change a few `"//` to `"https://` and `ios-app://` to `ios-app:https://`

Answer (score 1):

Ok im a goose. Looks like tumblr has changed their requirements on http. I know it sounds obvious but i couldn't tell why it was happening on every theme apart from their default theme. The reason is you need to go in and change the tumblr links to css and java from http to https "http://static.tumblr.com/xlsgtjb/WEMoeha97/style.css becomes https://static.tumblr.com/xlsgtjb/WEMoeha97/style.css" If you still get the alert after this try searching for other urls and delete or change them to https

Comment: Did a search/replace all in theme editor -> save -> fail.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem, and I thought all I have to do was changing the encryption to "Always serve blog over SSL" in the blog settings, like this: [Blog settings, encryption](https://i.stack.imgur.com/arrVn.png)

Apparently not, because the problem isn't just in the *blog* URL but also in the customization section.

So you need to enter the section, go through all the code, find the http URLs and change them into https URLs.

Comment: Accordingly to [Tumblr support](https://support.tumblr.com/post/138103206102/ssl-security-which-has-been-available-on-the): 

> Yet another update: SSL is now being turned on by default for ALL
> Tumblrs that use our Official theme on the web. Even though we don’t
> recommend it, you can still turn it off in your blog settings.

Answer (score 0):

<sup>Before you begin, make a backup of your existing html in case there is an issue. There are a few ways to do this but I recommend doing both of the following.</sup>

<sup>First, select all in the Tumblr html editor and copy and then paste the contents into a text file text editor on your computer and save the file. This backup is preferred.</sup>

<sup>Next, save a copy of the html for your main tumblr page. You can use `wget` which will result in an `index.html` file or you can right-click on your page, select "view source" and then select all, copy, and then paste that into a text editor. If the preferred backup fails for whatever reason, this one can be used as an alternative.</sup>

---

Now, to fix the problem.

First, open the Tumblr html editor and left-click anywhere in the html code and then press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> to use the "Search For" and "Replace With" feature.

Search for: `http://` and replace with: `https://` and then click on **All** to replace all.

Search for: `"//` and replace with: `"https://` and then click on **All** to replace all.

Search for: `android-app://` and replace with: `android-app:https://` and then click on **All** to replace all.

Search for: `ios-app://` and replace with: `ios-app:https://` and then click on **All** to replace all.

Search for: `http-equiv` and replace with: `https-equiv` and then click on **All** to replace all.

Finally, click on **Update Preview** to verify your changes. If everything looks good and your page displays fine, click **Save**.

---

As mentioned by others, the CSS fields are most important. If you are still getting an error, Search For `css` and click through the results while inspecting the code that follows under each CSS section to make sure all links are https. This is how I discovered `"//`

However it should be noted that, at least for me, the code did update despite the error. Even when I got an error, I noticed that the changes were applied and remained after closing and reopening the html editor.