# Custom Tumblr theme wont save because of non-https urls message that keeps popping up after trying to save my tumblr theme?

Tags: themes, tumblr

Let me know hw to solve it! Please since I need to change a part of my theme thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Custom Tumblr theme wont save because of non-https urls?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54088449/custom-tumblr-theme-wont-save-because-of-non-https-urls)

Comment: This likely means you've included `http://` assets in your theme - images, JavaScript, CSS, etc. - and that Tumblr is now requiring them all to be available over `https://` instead. You'll have to go through the theme and change everything to HTTPS (and ensure each asset is *available* that way).

Answer (score -3):

Just replace all the `http://`s to `https://`.